# I have two tables and need to join them

Tags: mysql, join

*First table:*

```
id | username | firstname |  surname  | address
---+----------+-----------+-----------+---------
1  | johnie   | john      | something | blabla
2  | alice    | something | something | blabla
3  | bar      | cola      | something | blabla
4  | whiskey  | whiskey   | something | blabla
```

*Second table:*

```
aincrement | id | user_id
-----------+----+---------
1          | 1  | 3
2          | 1  | 4
3          | 2  | 3
```

If I do

```
SELECT username, firstname, surname 
FROM first_table 
WHERE username != "johnie"
```

I get all the rows except johnie...

If I do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.user_id 
FROM second_table AS T1 
JOIN second_table AS T2 ON T1.id = T2.id 
WHERE T1.id = 1 AND T2.user_id <> 1
```

*I get 3,4*

But i would like to get 3 and 4 with all the others details (username, firstname, surname....)

*My expected output*

```
id | username | firstname |  surname  | address
---+----------+-----------+-----------+---------
3  | bar      | cola      | something | blabla
4  | whiskey  | whiskey   | something | blabla
```

I have to use `where username="johnie"` *(`first_table`)*. That user has id 1. Then I need to obtain `user_id(s)` from `second_table` (3, 4) and in output I need only basic info for users with id 3 and 4.

Comment: For id 1, do you want to get 3 or 4? Or both?

Comment: Both. And for id 2 I would like to get 3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `GROUP BY`, if you only need the basic information from `first_table`:

```
SELECT
    T1.id,
    T1.username,
    T1.firstname,
    T1.surname,
    T1.address
FROM first_table AS T1
JOIN second_table AS T2 ON (T2.user_id=T1.id)
JOIN first_table AS T3 ON (T3.id=T2.id AND T3.id<>T2.user_id)
WHERE T3.username='johnie' 
GROUP BY T1.id;
```

Try it in **[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63e46/3)**.

You can also test it with `T3.username='alice'`.

Comment: This query gives me almost same result as my second query (usersids). I need basic information from first_table for "usersids" and I have to use username="johnie"

Comment: Can you add your expected output in your question?

Comment: where username="johnie"....  Output is now the same as select * from first_table?

Comment: I have to use where username="johnie" (first_table). That user has id 1. Then I need to obtain user_id(s) from second_table (3,4) and in output I need only basic info for users with id 3 and 4.

Comment: I've update the answer, try now.